# Кэширующий SOCKS-прокси

Tags: linux, debian, proxy, кэширование, socks5

В настоящий момент у меня есть следующая схема: запускается браузер (хром), ему указывается SOCKS-прокси (собственной разработки), через который идёт выход в интернет по хитрым правилам. Работает это под Debian Stretch.

Мне нужно встроить в эту схему кэширование статики (HTTP/HTTPS, HTTP2). Скорее всего хотелось бы иметь какой-то софт между браузером и между конечным софтом, который принимал бы подключение по SOCKS, кэшировал статику, и если нужно - передавал бы подключение на последующий SOCKS.

Что можно под это дело использовать? - Как я понял из документации squid - там такого режима работы нет (если есть - подскажите конкретную конфигурацию, пожалуйста).

Comment: для socks это крайне сложно сделать. потому что он вообще к web (http) никакого отношения не имеет. Когда вам передадут команду на соединение с удаленным сервером, по хорошему вы должны ее уже выполнить. Но в команде на соединение еще нет URL куда пойдет запрос и зачастую нет даже имени хоста (только ip) и вы не знаете потребуется ли вообще это соединение, когда станет ясно что именно запрашивают и не поднять ли это из кеша. Фактически вам надо нарушить протокол, сделать вид, что соединение установлено, принять запрос от клиента, а после этого можно по протоколу web-proxy отдать его squid

Comment: Ну и через такой механизм никогда не пройдет https, потому что там стороны должны согласовать сертификаты до того, как можно будет узнать URL. Стоит все таки использовать протокол web-proxy, где в команде на соединение сразу есть URL

Comment: Касаемо SOCKS - решил обойти проблему. В браузере буду указывать HTTP-прокси ведущий на какой-то кэширующий софт, а подключения с этого кэширующего софта буду уже через badvpn заворачивать на SOCKS.

Осталась лишь проблема в том, что нет нормального кэширующего прокси с поддержкой HTTP2. По крайней мере гугл ничего хорошего не нашёл. Пока остановился на mitmproxy, к нему будет относительно легко добавить кэширование статики.